# How to preserve terminal colors on remote server?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, colors, color-profiles

I define my terminal colors in `~/.Xresources`. E.g. for my dark blue I have a line `*color4: #7cafc2`. This works on my local terminal.

When I ssh to a remote server, some of the terminal programs use completely different colors. E.g. `ls` prints directory names with deep blue color that is difficult to read on black background.

Interestingly, if I display all colours using script from this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/279014/1055185 that dark blue shade is not even present in the list of displayed colors. So it's not like ls uses different colors from the scheme. It uses entirely different color scheme.

Some other programs on remote server, e.g. vim editor display colors correctly, as I set them in my .Xresources on my local machine.

What might be overriding my color settings, and what can I do to have my preferred colors on remote machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a terminal SSH session (and not running a terminal emulator on the remote machine via X11 forwarding), then the colors displayed are completely chosen by your local terminal.  The only thing the remote system can do to influence the color of the terminal is send an escape sequence; your local terminal then interprets that and decides what to display.

The thing you need to look at is what the value of `TERM` is on both systems, and you can do that by running `echo $TERM`.  It may also be interesting to see what `echo $COLORTERM` says, since some programs will enable true color mode if that's set to `truecolor`.

In general, most terminals where the `TERM` string ends in `-256color` or `-direct` will support true color, and all of those ending in `-256color` will support 256 colors.  It's possible that your program is sending a true color sequence or a color that isn't in the normal 16-color palette but is one of the extended 240 colors.

If you want to see the escape sequences, you can invoke the program `script`, run `ls`, and then exit the shell that `script` spawns.  That will save the entire contents of the terminal session into the file `typescript` and then you can inspect the color sequences being used with a program like `od` or `xxd`.

If you'd prefer a standard 16-color palette, you can adjust your terminal emulator to use a `TERM` value that lacks the `-256color` or `-direct` prefix.  How you do that depends on your system and terminal emulator, so you should consult the documentation.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware a terminal can display more than 16 colors! So I found indeed that the remote server I use sets LS_COLORS variable. As it's ls what annoyed me the most, I simply added `unset LS_COLORS` to `.bashrc` so that I don't loose 256 color capability in general... just in case I find a cool application for it!